# Add selected class to each clicked item in ngFor

Tags: css, angular

Issue: With the current code, when i click an item, it correctly adds the "selected" class to the clicked item, but when i click another option, the "selected" class gets removed from it and gets added to the newly clicked item.

Wanted: I want to have the selected class added to all items which have been selected, my code is below, would appreciate any help:

My Html:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
 <div *ngFor="let event of groupSelections; let i = index;" class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
     <div class="row">
       <div *ngFor="let team of event?.Actors; first as isFirst" class="col-6">
         <div class="row">
           <div *ngIf="isFirst" class="col-6">
          <div>
              {{ team?.ActorName }}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div [className]="selectedValue == team?.Players ?'selected':''">
            <select (change)="getSelections(team, event, $event, team?.Players)">
              <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>SELECT</option>
              <option value="" *ngFor="let player of team?.Players; let j = index">
                {{ player?.Name }}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!isFirst" class="col-6">
          <div>
            {{ team?.ActorName }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My function:

```
getSelections(actors, event, selectedOption, player): any {
    const selections = [];
    this.selectedTeam = actors;
    this.selectedTeamPlayers = actors.Players;
    this.gameEvent = event;
    this.selectedValue = player;

    selections.push({
        EventId: this.gameEvent.EventId,
        ActorId: this.selectedTeam.ActorId,
        EventActorId: this.selectedTeam.EventActorId,
        Score: 1,
        Position: 1,
        PlayerPosition: this.player.Position,
        PlayerPoint: this.player.Point,
      });
    this.playerSelections = selections;
}
```

My Data:

```
groupSelections = [
{
  "PromotionId": 5,
  "Events": [
    {
      "Actors": [
        {
          "ActorId": 33,
          "ActorName": "Italy",
          "Players": [
            {
              "Name": " Mattia De Sciglio (D)",
              "Position": "DEFENDER",
              "Point": 5
            },
            {
              "Name": "Bryan Cristante (M)",
              "Position": "MIDFIELDER",
              "Point": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ActorId": 34,
          "ActorName": "Turkey",
          "Players": [
            {
              "Name": " Zeki Çelik (D)",
              "Position": "DEFENDER",
              "Point": 5
            },
            {
              "Name": "Ozan Tufan (M)",
              "Position": "MIDFIELDER",
              "Point": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Actors": [
        {
          "ActorId": 77,
          "ActorName": "Slovakia",
          "Players": [
            {
              "Name": "Mattia Perin (G)",
              "Position": "GOALKEEPER",
              "Point": 10
            },
            {
              "Name": "Bryan Cristante (M)",
              "Position": "MIDFIELDER",
              "Point": 3
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "ActorId": 78,
          "ActorName": "Sweden",
          "Players": [
            {
              "Name": " Zeki Çelik (D)",
              "Position": "DEFENDER",
              "Point": 5
            },
            {
              "Name": "Ozan Tufan (M)",
              "Position": "MIDFIELDER",
              "Point": 3
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should add a `selected` field to your `Players` object. Then you can set it to `true` and consider it when adding the additional class.

But let's do it with a simple array first.

**TS file**

```
selectedPlayers: Array<string> = [];

 // check whether the players object is in the list
 isSelectedPlayer(players: any): boolean {
     return this.selectedPlayers.findIndex(element => element === players) > -1;
 }

getSelections(actors, event, selectedOption, player): any {
    const selections = [];
    this.selectedTeam = actors;
    this.selectedTeamPlayers = actors.Players;
    this.gameEvent = event;

    // add the selection to your list, if is not in it
    if (this.selectedPlayers.findIndex(element => element === player) === -1) {
        this.selectedPlayers.push(player);
    }
    
    selections.push({
        EventId: this.gameEvent.EventId,
        ActorId: this.selectedTeam.ActorId,
        EventActorId: this.selectedTeam.EventActorId,
        Score: 1,
        Position: 1,
        PlayerPosition: this.player.Position,
        PlayerPoint: this.player.Point,
   });
   this.playerSelections = selections;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div [className]="gameEvent == event && isSelectedPlayer(team?.Players) ? 'selected':''">
```

Comment: Thank you sir, works as it should, had to remove this "gameEvent == event && "

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to hear, that it works.